# Difference between two time values in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT [TR_DATE]
      ,[TR_TIME]
      ,RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar,TR_TIME), 6)
      ,TIMEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar,TR_TIME), 6),1,2), SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar,TR_TIME), 6),3,2), SUBSTRING(RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar,TR_TIME), 6),5,2),0,0) as trtime
      ,[ET_TYPENO]
      ,[ET_NAME]
  FROM [DB400].[dbo].[TRANSACTIONREPORT]
  where DEPT_NAME = 'GIJIMA AST HOLDINGS (PTY) LTD'
  /*and LOC_NAME = 'Front Door and Gate'*/
  and TR_DATE between '20200120' and '20200130'
  order by TR_DATE, MST_LASTNAME, MST_FIRSTNAME, TR_TIME
```

which returns the following data:

[image]

I would like to use this to calculate the time the was spent in the building.

Note that ET_TYPENO = 1 equates to "Allowed Normal In" and ET_TYPENO = 2 to "Allowed Normal Out"

I have the following expression inside an ssrs report

```
=iif(Fields!ET_TYPENO.Value=2,
DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, previous(Fields!trtime.Value),Fields!trtime.Value),
"")
```

But it resolves to the following `#Error`.

**UPDATE**

Expected Result

Calculate the time difference between the "Allowed Nornmal In" event and the "Allowed Normal Out" event.

Take line 2 and 3 for example. "Allowed Nornmal In" occured at 07:23:19 and "Allowed Normal Out" occured at 08:55:48. I need it to return the time difference between these two times. I.E. 1:32:29.

Comment: can you add what is your desired result, this will help understand what exactly you need

Comment: Two things: Based on you sample data yo would never get an interval returned as your `ET_TYPENO` column is 1or 2, not "OUT" as you expression is checking for. Try changingthe final "" to `Nothing` as this will prevent data type issues.

Comment: thanks @AlanSchofield. the `"out"` was a typo. It is 2 in the actual code. Thanks for suggesting the `NOTHING` type.

Comment: @AnkUser Please see the update for the expected outcome

Comment: What's the error message? It should give a slightly helpful description in the Error List.

Comment: @HannoverFist I don't get an error message. `#error` is displayed instead of the time differecne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the suggestion from Honnover Fist's answer that the parameter of the DateDiff need to be Dates instead of Times. (The Documentation does say that a Time will work). I have changed my query to a `DATETIMEFROMPARTS()` instead of a `TIMEFROMPARTS()`.

Then I changed the condition to the below code so that the hours would be displayed more accurately.

```
=IIF(Fields!ET_TYPENO.Value = 2, 
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, previous(Fields!TR_DATETIME.Value), Fields!TR_DATETIME.Value) / 60,
    NOTHING)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `trtime` needs to be converted to a DATE type with the CDATE() function to use the DATEDIFF function.

```
=IIF(Fields!ET_TYPENO.Value = "OUT", 
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, CDATE(previous(Fields!trtime.Value)), CDATE(Fields!trtime.Value)),
    NOTHING)
```

Also, shouldn't `Fields!ET_TYPENO.Value = 1` ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'm still getting error.

Comment: I have changed my query to a DATETIMEFROMPARTS() instead of a TIMEFROMPARTS().